# "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /." while booting

Tags: boot, disk-check

This is message I get when I turn laptop on, have tried various things but nothing helps. Not an IT wizard so basic instructions to help would be appreciated. Screen reads:

```
Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.   
Press F to attempt to fix the errors, I to ignore, S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery...
```

Any ideas please

Comment: I have had the same symptoms on my ancient laptop especially after long use prior to shutdown (sometimes /tmp not available). My solution was to either run BleachBit or Ubuntu Tweak (Janitor) right before shutdown. I've practiced that for 2 weeks and I haven't had a re-occurrence since. Bleach bit is available in Software center. If you choose BB I suggest NOT running as root mode

Comment: if you press <F> here then you will see this error `The disk drive /tmp is not ready yet or not present.` then you can fix that with above ^-^ flag

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. That's not good..

Generally, the error that you have stated here indicates that there is some sort of problem with the hard drive or partition that is indicated in the message - in your case, this is stating that "/" is the problem, which is the root of your filesystem (where 'Linux is installed').

What happens when you press 'F' to attempt to fix?  Are you able to push past and get Ubuntu to boot up?

You may also want to try manually scanning the hard drive for errors... One way to do this would be to put the Ubuntu Live CD (installation CD) in and boot from it.  You could then use Disk Utility to browse for the drive/partition in question and scan it for errors via 'Check Filesystem' (this article shows a screenshot of what I am describing: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37659/the-beginners-guide-to-linux-disk-utilities/)